# How to store two different values in two different variables of the same input?

Tags: javascript

I have one input type number and what to store in different variables the different values of that same input. Example variable number1 will have an input.value of 5 and variable number2 will have an input.value of 3, from the same input.
This is what I've tried so far, I know this is not right because will give empty string, but that's the reason I am asking for help.

```
let input = document.querySelector('#input');
let output = document.querySelector('#output');

let number1 = input.value;
console.log('this is number1' + number1);


input.value = '' ;

if( number1) {
  let number2 = document.querySelector('#input');
  number2 = number2.value;
  console.log('this is number2' + number2);
}


output.innerHTML = input.value ;
```

```
 <input id="input" type="number" placeholder="choose a number here">
 <div id="output" class="visor"></div>
```

Comment: you set the value of the #input element to empty string. What did you expect to get from it when you query its value immediately after?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code doesn't make sense?!

Comment: I know that... that's why I am asking for help. I expect someone to give a solution to have two values of the same input and stored in two different variables.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't meant to be a bad guy, ok why do you need only one input, you can use two input elements and store the value of the first in a variable and the second in another variable?

Answer (score 0):

Input will always be `''`

```
let input = document.querySelector('#input');
let output = document.querySelector('#output');

let number1 = input.value;
console.log('this is number1' + number1);


input.value = '' ; // <-- You're setting the value of #input here

if( number1) {
  let number2 = document.querySelector('#input');
  number2 = number2.value;
  console.log('this is number2' + number2);
}


output.innerHTML = input.value ;
```

Comment: yes I know, that s why I am asking if there is a way to store two values of the same input in two different variables.

Comment: @RaquelSantos How are you going to get two values out of a singe `<input>`? The only thing I could see being useful is using an onchange event